# How to disable/freeze Ribbon WorkBench button (CRM)?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I need to freeze/disable a Ribbon WorkBench button while the JS function is running (to prevent it to click and run the js logic twice). I was trying to google find information but there a lot of examples how to disable the simple form header elements but not the Ribbon WorkBench.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to show Progress modal using `showProgressIndicator` and `closeProgressIndicator` to release it. This will freeze the whole form.

```
function getPrimaryContactEmail()
{
    Xrm.Utility.showProgressIndicator("Loading contact email..");

    var contact = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("primarycontactid").getValue();
    if(contact == null){
       Xrm.Utility.closeProgressIndicator();
       return;
    }
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("contact", contact[0].id, "$select=emailaddress1")
    .then(function(result) {
        var email = result["emailaddress1"];
        Xrm.Utility.closeProgressIndicator();

    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.closeProgressIndicator();
        var message = error.message;

    });
}
```

[Read more](https://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/dynamics-365-v9-progress-indicator-api/)